# How to put ExoPlayer controller under PlayerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to put `PlayerControlView` under `PlayerView` and control `PlayerView` with `PlayerControlView`.

This is my xml code for it.

```xml
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container_appbar"
            app:use_controller="false"
            app:resize_mode="fit" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
            android:id="@+id/exo_controller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/exoplayer"
            app:show_timeout="0" />
```

And this is my Kotlin code.

```kotlin
player = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).build()
binding.exoController.player = player
binding.exoplayer.player = player
player.apply{
    setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    addListener(onPlayStateChangeListener)
    prepare()
}
```

After setting them the controller doesn't work and when I printed duration and visibility for `binding.exocontroller`, it printed -9223372036854775807 and invisible.

I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own player controls for this

For example instead of controller UI add an ImageView as play button, then in your activity add this code

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener{player.play()}
```

Comment: This solution will not help to resolve the problem, PlayerControlView has a lot of controller buttons, and you don't need to recreate all this functionality from the beginning, so we need to find the problem with exo player initialization instead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).